# UICollectionView перевернуть Layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Имеется задача, сделать список "как чат". Ну т.е. скролл будет снизу вверх, но при этом мне нужно оставить все возможности `UICollectionView`. Что я пытался делать, я пытался использовать `UITableView` и вставлять в начало, очень костыльно получалось и не всегда красиво + достаточно долго это делалось на старых устройствах. Дальше я попытался перевернуть таблицу и все было хорошо, но анимации были не красивыми (reloadSection -> получалось что новые данные уезжали вверх, так как таблица перевернута, и с этим ничего придумать не удалось). Решено было использовать UICollectionView так как там, якобы, можно настроить Layout, но все решения которые я нашел, вставляли контент вниз (и верх оставался сверху), мне надо как то сконфигурировать этот Layout так что бы ячейки добавлялись снизу (а-ля insertItemsAtIndexPaths:0 - добавилось вниз)

Comment: то есть вам надо добавить в датасурс новый объект с индексом 0, посчитать его высоту, перерисовать таблицу и сдвинуть ее на высоту новой ячейки, чтоб визуально она осталась там же?

Comment: Да, типа того. Поведение должно быть как у перевернутой коллекции, но на самом деле она не должна быть перевернутой